# XML parsing with different attributes?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom

I have an example of XML file below.

The question is how can I parse each "record" and put it into the array ready for dump into the database with columns

#### SQL Table Structure

- Country_Code
- Item_name
- Year
- Value

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:wb="http://www.worldbank.org">
  <data>
    <record>
      <field name="Country or Area" key="THA">Thailand</field>
      <field name="Item" key="AG.AGR.TRAC.NO">Agricultural machinery, tractors</field>
      <field name="Year">1960</field>
      <field name="Value" />
    </record>
    <record>
      <field name="Country or Area" key="THA">Thailand</field>
      <field name="Item" key="AG.AGR.TRAC.NO">Agricultural machinery, tractors</field>
      <field name="Year">1961</field>
      <field name="Value">5000</field>
    </record>
    <record>
      <field name="Country or Area" key="THA">Thailand</field>
      <field name="Item" key="AG.AGR.TRAC.NO">Agricultural machinery, tractors</field>
      <field name="Year">1962</field>
      <field name="Value">5000</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</Root>
```

Comment: The answer is: With [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), some foreach-loops and some functions of your database-class. (*Please show some effort, it's really not hard to find what you're looking for on google (or even among the related questions - this has been asked thousands of times!)! Feel free to ask some more specific questions if you encounter any problems, but don't ask us to write your code for you.*)

Comment: like already commented, you don't even need to turn this into an array first with SimpleXML. http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)